# form["x"] throws a KeyError

Tags: python, html, cgi

I'm working on an assignment and we are to create a HTML order form then execute the info by python to create a second customer receipt.

Here is the error msg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Assignment 3\page.py", line 17, in <module>
    print "<p>Customer Name:", form["custName"].value, "</p>"
  File "C:\Python27\lib\cgi.py", line 540, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError, key
KeyError: 'custName'
```

THE HTML:

```
<form action="page.py">

<div class="personalinfohead">
    <p>Personal Information:</p>
</div>

<div class="personalinfo">
    <div>Full name:
        <input type="text" name="custName" size="20" />
    </div>

    <div>Email address:
        <input type="text" name="custEmail"  size="50" />
    </div>

    <div>Street address:
        <input type="text" name="custAdd"  size="50" />
    </div>

    <div>City:
        <input type="text" name="custCity"  size="15" />
    </div>

    <div>Province:
        <input type="text" name="custProv"  size="2" maxlength="2" />
    </div>

    <div>Postal code:
        <input type="text" name="custPostal"  size="6" maxlength="6" />
    </div>
</div>
```

PYTHON:

```
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

# print HTTP/HTML header stuff
print """Content-type: text/html

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html><head>
<title>Order Form</title>
</head><body>
"""

# print HTML body using form data
print "<h1>Kintoro Japanese Bar &amp; Restaurant</h1>"
print "<h2>Customer Reciept</h2>"
print "<p>Customer Name:", form["custName"].value, "</p>"
print "<p>Customer Email Address:", form["custEmail"].value, "</p>"
print "<h2>Customer Address:</h2>"
print "<p>Street:", form["custAdd"].value, "</p>"
print "<p>City:", form["custCity"].value, "</p>"
print "<p>Province:", form["custProv"].value, "</p>"
print "<p>Postal Code:", form["custPostal"].value, "</p>"
```

Comment: What is in `form`? It looks like your data isn't populating properly. Thrown in a debugging statement like `print form` before trying to access it.

Comment: The KeyError in your first error message means that there is no "custName" key in the form dictionary.

Comment: form is the <form> tag i used to create the html order form. I followed the teacher's instruction in that but I don't understand why it's showing up as an error..

Comment: and yes I know what KeyError refers to, but i clearly named the <input> textbox as custName so idk :/

Comment: Are you putting a value into the custName field when you test? If not, that's the reason. You probably want to do  `form = cgi.FieldStorage(keep_blank_values=True)`

Comment: I replaced that but still shows the same error msg :(

Comment: What about when you try? `form = cgi.FieldStorage(strict_parsing=True)`

Comment: still doesn't work.. I'm about to cry LOL appreciate your help though!

Comment: now it shows this:

  File "C:\Users\Priscilla\Desktop\CMPT Assn #3\page.py", line 17, in <module>
    print "<p>Customer Name:", form["custName"].value, "</p>"
TypeError: 'classobj' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: What's the rest of your html? I assume there's a submit button somewhere?

Comment: By the way, I personally don't use CGI, but prefer HTTP, so you can try your program locally with much ease, and your program is already started when the request comes: it's faster. To configure it's easy, use a "proxy" instead of a "cgi gate". Typically you may try Cherrypy or Pyramid.

Answer (score 0):

Jack is correct, but there is a backstory and quick/dirty testing method for the future students.

Explanation first:

Originally, your KeyError said there was no **Key** with that name.  After you've implicitly stated a key (the first part of a dict), it was then missing the **Value** for said key.

Dictionaries are a key-value pair, so both would need to be implicitly stated at the start of the script (in the scope the previous and following debugging-with-ease methods).

Slowing down the actions helps obtain clearer understanding;

Since this script is a fully loaded CGI that is told to start and finish by declaring variables for each key-value pair, you are seeing the end result of which - where python feeds text data to CGI, CGI then accepts and interprets said text, and gives some sort of response back to python (valid or not!), python can only give you the results of the results.  Thusly, this error looks different than your standard (and excellent I may add) non-cgi / console error with followable tracebacks.

A quick/dirty test method:

Implicitly state an exact key-value pair before telling CGI to pass it back to python to use:

```
custName = { 'Name': 'John Smith' }
```

One would need to declare a default setting for each dict mentioned as values to have a fully operational loaded script ready to use, but the hint here is that custName would no longer present the error, but it would then complain about your next missing key-value pair.

Yeah, long answer and past classtime - I know.  Hopefully, however, this will assist to understand the several parts of a 'single' issue than to solve it once for only a select few people.